# Dom insert the cursor into data text field

Tags: javascript, dom, datatextfield

I'm a beginner to HTML DOM and what I want to achieve is focus `textarea` so that cursor will be placed in it to type.

```
<div class="_4bl9">
  <div class=" _30z _4h96">
    <textarea name="xhpc_message_text" placeholder="Write something..." class="_4h98"></textarea>
    <input value="" name="xhpc_message" type="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
```

I was using this code before and it was working but not anymore.

```
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message')[0].focus()
```

Can any one suggest me other way to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message_text')[0].focus()
```

```html
<div class="_4bl9">
  <div class=" _30z _4h96">
    <textarea name="xhpc_message_text" placeholder="Write something..." class="_4h98"></textarea>
    <input value="" name="xhpc_message" type="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a typo in your script. It's not `xhpc_message` it is `xhpc_message_text`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to place the cursor in the `textarea`, instead of the `input` field, because the `input` field is hidden.

If that's what you want to do, the name you use to select the element in your previous code isn't correct, it should be `xhpc_message_text`.

The following example places the cursor in the `textarea`:

```
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message_text')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message_text')[0].select();
```